# Make an HTTP request non-replayable

Tags: security, http, denial-of-service

I have an application that runs on for example Google TV or Apple TV, which sends HTTP requests to a service of mine.

Now if someone listens in on this request, they can replay it and in that way execute a Denial of Service (DOS) attack our service.

Is there any way to make each request unique, so it cannot be replayed?

I thought of sending the time encrypted in the request and check the difference between the server time and the time the request was sent, but I'm getting too big time differences to compare.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: What you are talking about is a MITM attack. Use HTTPS and this will be made so difficult as to be almost impossible.

Comment: @Dave the devices we are using doesn't support https so we kinda have to find another solution, any advise?

Comment: OK well the usual solution to this would be to have the server generate a one-time use key that the client can use, that the client then sends back to the server in e.g. a cookie. Once that key has been used, any further requests that present that key are rejected. Exactly how this is implemented depends on your architecture, but in essence what you are looking at is a variation on the theme of cookie authentication.

Comment: I wouldn't decribe this as a MITM attack (to me that implies someone modifying an existing data stream) this is a replay attack. There's lots of ways to provide protection, using a cookie has additional overheads (and complications) compared with sending back a single use token via POST or GET

Answer (score 1):

You are in a good situation as you have control both on the server side and the client side (your application is talking). Include into your message

- The current time in milliseconds plus + random number
- The combined hash produced by these values plus (as a the third input) some key only your application knows. Use some good one way hashing algorithm.

Only the code who knows the mentioned key will be able to compute a correct hash. The used request records (hash and time stamp) can be stored for some expiration time that can be long. Very old request records can be easily expired as they contain the time stamp.

The positive feature of the proposed approach is it does not require to connect in advance in order to receive a token, needs no authentication, needs no registration and can use the open protocol. Using token just by itself does not help much against DoS as an attacker quickly writes a script to connect and obtain the token in advance as well.